# How to get rid of white space between <a hrefs> and <img>

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a bunch of hrefs that have images inside to make a menu on the upper left corner of the page.  After the menu i have an image right next to it that expands to the end of the page.  However that image right now is dropped below the menu area.

How do I get rid of this white space?

```
.MenuArea
{
        position:relative;
        width:225px;
        height:300px;
        background-color:#666666;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
}
.MenuAreaImageSmall
{
    position:relative;
    left:225px;
    height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.MenuLink
{
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
    width:225px;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0 solid #ffffff;
}
.Href
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

                    $cpage = $page."ImgArea";
                    $query = "Select * FROM ContentTab WHERE InUse='Y' && PageAssignment='".$cpage."' && ContentType='Image' ORDER BY ContentOrder ASC";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                    $num = mysql_numrows($result);

                    $cpage1 = $page."Link";
                    $query = "Select * FROM ContentTab WHERE InUse='Y' && PageAssignment LIKE '".$cpage1."' && ContentType='Image' ORDER BY ContentOrder ASC";
                    $result1 = mysql_query($query);
                    $num1 = mysql_numrows($result1);

                    $n = 0;
                    $i = 0;
                    while($n < $num)
                    {
                        $image = mysql_result($result,$n,"Content");

                        if($cpage == "SolutionImgArea")
                        {
                            if($n == 0)
                            {
                                $output = "<div id=\"MenuAreaBox\" class=\"MenuArea\"/>\n";

                                while($i < $num1)
                                {
                                    $links = mysql_result($result1,$i,"PageAssignment");

                                    if($links == $cpage1)
                                    {
                                        $linkimg = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Content");
                                        $temp = $linkimg;
                                        list($linkimg2, $format) = split('[.]', $temp);
                                        $temp = $linkimg2;
                                        $linkimg2 .= "_roll.".$format;
                                        list($trash, $trash, $filename) = split('[/]', $temp);

                                        $output .= "<A href=\"test.php?page=Solution\" onmouseover=\"roll_over('".$filename."', '".$linkimg2."')\" onmouseout=\"roll_over('".$filename."', '".$linkimg."')\" class=\"Href\">";
                                        $output .= "<img name=\"".$filename."\" src=\"".$linkimg."\" alt=\"\" class=\"MenuLink\"/>";
                                        $output .= "</A>";
                                    }
                                    $i++;
                                }
                            }
                            if(($n+1) == $num)
                            {
                                //$output .= "                  </div>\n";
                                $output .= "<img src=\"".$image."\" class=\"MenuAreaImageSmall\" alt=\"\"/>";
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $output = "<img src=\"".$image."\" class=\"MenuAreaImageBig\" alt=\"\"/>";
                        }
                        $n++;
                    }
                    echo $output;?>
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to post a link to the page?, as I am having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: Also, since this is a html/css question (I assume) you only need to post the code of the generated page since that's what's being rendered. The SQL stuff is nice -if only for the purpose of completion- but it doesn't really contribute to the layout question, and serves to complicate the code for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

link to before:
test1.php

link to after:
http://www.gramercyit.com/test.php

Solved it by changing my position to absolute and setting top to 0px; Sorry to have wasted you guys time, i just didn't think that it would work that way heh.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try display:block, float:left for the img and a?

Answer (score 0):

Do not listen to anyone who says about removing white spaces - it will help, but only for some time, until your content will be modified by someone else who does not know the white space trick. :)

When you are assigning float: left to the element it is automatically converted to block-level element.

Therefore, if you want to get rid of the problem using CSS only, use display:block for the image.

If you are using text with images (which is not the case specified here), then use float: left or float:right.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was to assign the a tag display:block

the only problem with that is you need a container for the **a** and the **img**

```
<div class="image"><a href="#"><img src="blah.gif" /></a></div>

.image a,
.image img
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

an alternate solution is (***but really bad practice so I recommend against it***)

```
.image a
{
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Ultimately having a div around your image gives you a better time when creating responsive images and you want to give them borders (without it screwing your positioning), just apply the border to the container instead.